# combining a temp table with union query

Tags: sql-server-2008

So I have a query that I am working on. It will have ship, order, and return data in it by date and unit type.

I have each sub query working so they come together like this:

```
Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(ship)

union

Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(order)

union

Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(return)
```

Now not every date will have something in it, but I want to represent that date whether or not it has any date, for instance weekends.

So the same query has code to create a temp table called `#dates` with the field `lookupdate` which has been populated with each day of the current month.

I need to join the combined union queries with this table so that I have a record for each day of the month.

Comment: Try a left outer join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps easiest to read if you use a common table expression (CTE) for your union query and the join it to your dates.

```
;WITH cte AS (

Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(ship) type_total

union

Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(order)

union

Select dateproc,unit,totqty,type(return)
)
SELECT * 
  FROM #dates a
       LEFT JOIN
       cte b ON a.date = b.dateproc
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly...now the really fun part of data verification to make sure all my numbers match..